# Black screen after logging in from terminal (Debian 10)

Tags: debian, debian-buster

Nothing except for the mouse cursor was displayed on the monitor after I logged in from the keyboard. SSHed in I was able to see myself logged in from tty7. Restarting the display manager brought the display back to the login screen. I entered my credential and it went to black screen again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try ....    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove  .... and then restart, test.  Can you update drivers?  Like Video?

Comment: Will try these. It seems the problem is with my account. I just created a new account and used it to log in from keyboard. All seems good. Are there configuration files in my account that I should check?

Comment: It appears you had an account issue. The commands I posted are for all accounts (that is for your machine)